# "No overload matches this call" while constructing Map from array

Tags: typescript

`new Map([[1, [2, 3]] ].map(e => e[1]));` is perfectly valid javascript. But typescript gives the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(number | number[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<number | number[], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [unknown, unknown], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<number | number[]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [unknown, unknown], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<number | number[]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [unknown, unknown]>'.
              Type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [unknown, unknown]'.
                Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'readonly [unknown, unknown]'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[] | null | undefined): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(number | number[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[]'.
      Type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [unknown, unknown]'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'readonly [unknown, unknown]'.
```

It seems the compiler is matching the signature of `Map` with `[[1, [2, 3]]` instead of the transformed `[2, 3]`.

Follow ups if `Map` takes only readonly array:

1. Why `new Map([[2, 3]]);` is correct?
2. Why `new Map(Object.freeze([[1, [2, 3]]].map(e => e[1])));` does not work even though `Object.freeze` returns `readonly` array?

TS compiler should theoretically be able to deduce the equivalence of all three forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's dig into type definition of `MapConstructor`

```js
interface MapConstructor {
    new(): Map<any, any>;
    new<K, V>(entries?: readonly (readonly [K, V])[] | null): Map<K, V>;
    readonly prototype: Map<any, any>;
}
```

According to the types, if you want to provide an array as an argument  - in our case `entries`, this array should be immutable.

Hence, in order to make it work just add `as const`.

```js
const arr = [[1, [2, 3]]] as const
const x = new Map(arr); // ok
```

OR

```js
const x = new Map( ([[1, [2, 3]]] as const).map(e => e[1])); // ok
```

> new Map([[2, 3]]); is correct?

See this type definition:

```js
interface MapConstructor {
    new(): Map<any, any>;
/* -----> */ new<K, V>(entries?: readonly (readonly [K, V])[] | null): Map<K, V>;
    readonly prototype: Map<any, any>;
}
```

Here, you have a deal with generics, so TS is able to infer form the argument the you have an array with exactly two elements (key and value). This is the most important thing. Because this is the nature of Map, you should have key and value.

Pls see [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and next example:

```js
const infer = <K, V>(arg: readonly [K, V]) => arg
const x = infer([1, 2])
```

As you see, because you have literal array, TS is able to figure out that you have exactly two values: key and value.

But, if you use reference as an argument (see excess property check again):

```js
const infer = <K, V>(arg: readonly [K, V]) => arg
const tuple = [1,2] // number[]
const x = infer(tuple)
```

TS will complain, baceuse `tuple` is infered as `number[]` and TS is unable to figure out how many elements do you have in your array. It can be even empty array. Thats why TS does not allow you to use reference to mutable arrays here.

> Why new Map(Object.freeze([[1, [2, 3]]].map(e => e[1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)))) does not work?

There is a big difference between:

```js
Object.freeze([[1, [2, 3]]].map(e => e[1]))
```

and

```js
([[1, [2, 3]]] as const).map(e => e[1])
```

In first case, you are able to mutate an array inside your `map` predicate, but you unable to mutate result.

In second case, you are unable to mutate an array inside your `map`.

Please see their type signatures:

```js
type First = readonly (number | number[])[]
type Second = (readonly [2, 3])[]

let x: First = [1] // is allowed but invalid argument
let y: Second = [1] // does not allowed, because we should have a kay and value. not only key
```

Comment: Thanks. Two questions: 1. Why `new Map([[2, 3]]);` is correct? 2. Why `new Map(Object.freeze([[1, [2, 3]]].map(e => e[1])));` does not work since `Object.freeze` returns `readonly` array? TS compiler should theoretically be able to deduce the equivalence of all three forms.